# JavaScript: Single quote ' causes error

Tags: javascript, html, quotes

I have a string with a ' inside it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('... &#039; ...')) { document.exampleFormName.submit(); }">example link text</a>
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. Firebug says "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" and you can see that the HTML entity has already been replaced by '.

What can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Try this.. `<a href="#" onclick='if (confirm("... &#039; ...")) { document.exampleFormName.submit(); }'>example link text</a>`

Comment: where is the "string with a ' inside it"

Comment: Well, of course it does, `&#039;` is a single quote, making it an entity doesn't help at all, you have to escape it, as in `\'`

Comment: Use `addEventListener` and forget the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z0x0swt8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href='#' onclick='if (confirm("... &#039; ...")) 
{ 
  document.exampleFormName.submit(); 
}'> example link text
</a>
```

Because "#039" stands for single quote so ('...'...') in your previous code would fail because of this reason

Comment: Thanks M3ghana. Eventhough this may not be best practise, it's the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 5):

It's not beautiful to write like that XD

```
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('... &#039; ...')) { document.exampleFormName.submit(); }">example link text</a>
```

It's better to use a function

```
<script>
  function foo() {
    if (confirm("...' ...")) { document.exampleFormName.submit(); }
    return false; // disable the link
  }
</script>
<a href='#' onclick='return foo()'>example link text</a>
```

but maybe that just me..

Comment: I would go with its just you. Sometimes you just want to use an inline function.

Comment: The web application I am working with is not beautiful at all :D It's full of bad code style.

Answer (score 3):

You should escape quotes. not use html entities. 
In a '' string you use \' to escape single quotes.

Read more about escape characters: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes

```html
    
    <a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('... \' ...')) { document.exampleFormName.submit(); }">example link text</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the best general solution. :)

Comment: Why did you choose to accept the worst solution of them all? You should place the checkmark at the answer that most benefits you and future readers. That's either my answer which is to the point of your question, or @Kokizzu which gives a nicer solution which is easier to maintain. Remember, your accepted answer will guide people who have similar problems like you.

Comment: Because this is not about finding the best solution for the general escaping problem but about what helps **me** the most. :p